# serviceStack.Text .ToJson extension method option to output empty array for null list<T> property

Tags: json, knockout.js, mongodb-.net-driver, knockout-mapping-plugin, servicestack-text

There's a bit of work to set the stage, so please bear with me...

I'm using knockout to databind a rather deeply nested data structure.  When I retrieve the data from the database (from MongoDB using the Mongo C# Driver) there are nested properties (of type `List<T>`) that aren't populated and are returned as null.  I'm using the ServiceStack.Text .ToJson extension method to serialize this data structure to JSON that gets passed to the client for knockoutMapper to convert into my observable viewModel.  All goes well, except for the `List<T>` properties that were null on the server.  Since they arrive at the client with a null value, knockoutMapper just makes them observables instead of observableArrays.  Now for the question... Is there any way to tell ServiceStack that I want any property of type `List<T>` that is empty to be serialized as an empty array?  I've dug through the JsConfig object to find a setting that looks like it might help but haven't had any luck.  Am I missing something in JsConfig or is this something I should be doing in knockoutMapping on the client?

EDIT: Just a note - this is a side project where I'm learning 3-4 new technologies and I have come to see how absurd it is to retrieve JSON from Mongo, use the C# driver to convert this to a POCO to work with it on the server, then to use serviceStack to serialize the POCO as JSON.  I plan on changing this with a straight through shot of just JSON, but this is a learning process for me.

Comment: Not as absurd as you think and pretty much standard practice. It's not JSON when talking to MongoDB anyway, it's BSON. And your API **should** be able to serialize other formats than JSON on it's client side.

Comment: Have you tried declaring a default value such as an empty list? That's usually the way in other language implementations.

Comment: I guess I could do that, just have to decide where it makes the most sense to do it - server or client side.